# Why is $|dx-c|<|qx-p|$ the condition for the best rational approximations of the second kind

Tags: number-theory, optimization, diophantine-approximation

> The fraction $c/d$ is a best approximation of the second kind for a number $x$ if for every other fraction $p/q$ with $q<d$, $|dx-c|<|qx-p|$

Given a number $x$, its best rational approximations of the first kind are those fractions $c/d$ that satisfy $|x-c/d|<|x-p/q|$ for any other fraction $p/q$ where $q<d$.

We are trying to approximate a number $x$ by combining $1/q$ which we do $p$ number of times. If we make $q$ larger, ie., $1/q$ becomes smaller, that means the building blocks become finer which makes the approximation more accurate. But, one can not make the building blocks $1/q$ infinitely smaller, there can be a practical maximum value which $q$ can be chosen. So we need to find the best approximation of $x$ for the chosen value of $q$.

So the idea of the best rational approximations of the first kind is that, $x$ is closer to $c/d$, ie., minimum error, than to any fraction with a smaller denominator.

In the condition for the best rational approximations of the second kind, the error is multiplied by the denominator, ie., $\color{red}{|dx-c|<|qx-p|}$. What is the logic behind setting such a condition to state it is the best approximation of a number ?

Comment: You want the error to be small, and the denominator not to be too big, so you kinda set a condition on both of them at once.

Comment: @IvanNeretin We can make the approximation more precise by making the denominator largest. The best approx of the first kind is, we want the error to be small for a particular diameter, that is how the condition $|x-c/d|<|x-p/q|$, right ?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Could you please elaborate more, I still don't understand the logic of the condition $|dx-c|<|qx-p|$.

Comment: There is no "largest". Greater denominators are still possible, but less desirable.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I agree. we are looking for the least error for the chosen denominator, that's what I understand in the approx of first kind.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but in the second kind, the quantity which is minimized is error multiplied by the denominator, I don't get why is that ?

Comment: Are there any letters that we didn't use as variable names yet? Say, $y$ and $z$. Say, you are solving some optimization problem of unspecified kind, and you want your $y$ to be small, but there is a catch: you want your $z$ to be small too. What would you minimize? If you minimize $y$, you $z$ will turn out not so small, and vice versa.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So we have two variables the error $e=|x-p/q|$ and the denominator $q$. we have chosen a maximum value $q=d$ and we want the error to be less and the denominator $q$ to be less too. The problem is, if we try to minimize the error $e$ beyond a certain value the denominator $q$ has to also increase, and vise ersa. This is understood. But, how does this imply that we want to minimize the product $qe$ ?

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Okay. If we choose a lower value denominator, say $q_1$ and the corresponding error $e_1$, gives the product $p_1=q_1e_1$. Now if we increase $q_1$ to a factor of $m$ to $q_2=mq_1$ then the error will decrease by a factor of $n$ to $e_2=e_1/n$, gives the product $p_2=q_2e_2=p_1m/n$. If $m>n$ then $p_1<p_2$, and we can say that increasing the denominator to $mq_1$ is not worth since the corresponding error will only decrease by $n<m$.So choosing $q_1$ will not give a good approximation. right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works.